# how to access an object property that has dash(-) in it

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, web-development-server

I'm working on a cricket API, in that team name is written as team-1 which I think is not valid format to define a property on an object.

check the image I provided.

I have tried these ways

```
<h3 class="display-6 text-center"> ${eachItem["team-1"]} VS ${eachItem.team-1} </h3>
```

but I'm still getting an error

[image: image of object property]

Comment: eachItem['team-1'] is how I write it, which should be equivalent to yours

Comment: You are accessing the property correctly in your code `${eachItem["team-1"]}` but not following the same in the second part of the expression(After `VS`), JS doesn't allow you to access the object property with the dash in it using dot notation, you should use bracket notation to access the properties in these cases, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: @PunithK  thansk alot for your help , it was some other problem . i was accessing wrong item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eachItem["team-1"] this should be fine. if its not, could be a different problem

```js
const hero = {
"spider-man" : 1
}
console.log(hero["spider-man"])
```

Comment: thanks alot for ur help, my mistake was that i was trying to access some other API  response which actualy didnt had this property :)

Answer (score 1):

`eachItem.team-1` is like doing `x - 1`. Dot takes precedence.

`eachItem["team-1"]` and `eachItem["team-2"]` should work for you.