# Data Fetching in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Let's say I wanted to fetch data from a website, and the link to that website is http://cookiestats.net/cookies, and the data on that link is this:

{"cookie-stats": {"eating": 1, "eaten": "6"}, "people-eating": {"current": 3, "total": "6"}}

What am I doing wrong?

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://cookiestats.net/cookies');
    const data = await res.json();
    
    return{
        props: {cookies: data}
    }
}

const Cookies = ({ cookies }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Cookie Data</h1>
            {Object.keys(cookies).map(cookies => (
                <div key = {cookies.cookie-stats}>
                    <a>
                        <h3>{cookies.eating}</h3>
                    </a>
                    </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Cookies;
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: If `cookies` is what you say it is, then it does not have a map property, and you should be getting an error.

Comment: The answer below fixed the error regarding mapping an object but now I'm getting this error: ReferenceError: stats is not defined. This error is in reference to the line: "<div key = {cookies.cookie-stats}>" I put the updated code above.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68237579/how-to-access-an-object-property-that-has-dash-in-it

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to map an object which is not possible. Instead you could try to use the method [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
 Object.keys(cookies).map(cookiesKey => (
     <div key = {cookies[cookiesKey]}>
         <a>
            <h3>{cookies[cookiesKey]}</h3>
         </a>
     </div>
 ))}
```

Comment: I'd say mapping is unnecessary. Just using the property directly will do

Comment: This fixed the error regarding mapping an object but now I'm getting this error: ReferenceError: stats is not defined. This error is in reference to the line: "<div key = {cookies.cookie-stats}>" I put the updated code above.

Comment: Check the solution I gave you, you are not applying it correctly. In your code you are trying to access the "cookies" inside .map which is not an object is just a string